# I want to catch click event of Ok button in tinyMCE image tools

Tags: javascript, tinymce-4

I want to catch the click event of OK button in tinyMCE image tools button, how do I can achieve this, attaching screenshot for your reference.

[image]

When someone clicks on Ok button, I want a user defined function to trigger. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

its already a couple of days old but...

This solution is a bit dirty imo but as long as you can't/won't edit the plugin itself you can get the button with:

```
// top.tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.windows[0].statusbar is the footer instance
var tinyMceFooterId = top.tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.windows[0].statusbar._id;
var tinyMceFooter = document.getElementById(tinyMceFooterId);
var tinyMceSubmitButton = tinyMceFooter.querySelector('.mce-primary button');
```

Keep in mind, that this will just work if there is a button inside the footer with the class "mce-primary" (the ok button) and it is the first one  – otherwise you have to edit the selector.

Not sure if there's a better way except extending/customizing the image plugin itself -> at least it works ;)

Cheers :)